# Regex for price sort url

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Iam not good on regex, I would be very thankful if somebody can solve my problem about this...i have some confusing about this:

```
echo (preg_match('/\/(price-100)/i','/index.php/search/price-100/')) ? 'Same' :'Not Same';
```

it would be result "Same", but when i change to price-10 or price-1

```
echo (preg_match('/\/(price-10)/i','/index.php/search/price-100/')) ? 'Same' :'Not Same';
```

it will result "Same" too...i think there's missed on the regex..anyone can help me please? thank you soo much before!

best regards,
Harrison

Answer (score 1):

Use a `\b` for word-boundary.

```
echo (preg_match('/\/(price-10)\b/i','/index.php/search/price-100/')) ? 'Same' :'Not Same';
```

Answer (score 0):

"price-100" starts with "price-10", so the regular expression matches.  If you want to only match price-10 when there aren't any more numbers after it, you need to change the expression to say that.

Here's one option:

```
'/\/(price-10)(?:$|\/)/'
```

That matches either ".../price-10" or ".../price-10/", but fails if anything other than a slash comes after the -10.  If that's too restrictive, you can do something like this:

```
'/\/(price-10)(?!\d)/'
```

which will match as long as there's not another digit after the -10.

Answer (score 0):

`(price-10)` replace with `(price-10?/)` and try

Answer (score 0):

You aren't terminating your regular expression. For example, the string "price-1" is found in:

1. price-1
2. price-10
3. price-100

So all three expressions will return true. You need to terminate the match with something like a word boundary, end-of-string, end-of-line, or other terminating character in order to have a unique match. See the PHP reference on [anchors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.anchors.php) for more information.